# logback logging with wrong timestamp

Tags: java, logback

I am trying to use the springboot logback logging framework to log my information. Unfortunately, when I log info warn error, time stamp is exactly same,are same as the application server start time.

```
My logback.xml configuration information is as follows:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.padual.com/java/logback.xsd"
        debug="false" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 second">
    <property name="PROJECT" value="AmazonRss" />
    <property name="ROOT" value="logs/${PROJECT}/" />
    <property name="FILESIZE" value="10MB" />
    <property name="MAXHISTORY" value="100" />
    <timestamp key="DATETIME" datePattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" />
    <!-- Console printing -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder charset="utf-8">
            <pattern>[%-5level] %d{${DATETIME}} [%thread] %logger{36} - %m%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

........
```

and my log are like:

```
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8888"]
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.a.c.core.AprLifecycleListener - The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6725 ms
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] com.denistek.rss.utils.SpringUtil - ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] com.denistek.rss.utils.SpringUtil - ========The ApplicationContext configuration is successful. In the normal class, you can get the applicationContext object by calling SpringUtils.getAppContext(). applicationContext=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@c818063, started on Wed Apr 17 16:48:45 CST 2019========
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver - Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper - Context refreshed
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper - Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner - Scanning for api listing references
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8888"]
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8888 (http) with context path ''
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [main] com.denistek.rss.RssApplication - Started RssApplication in 32.748 seconds (JVM running for 34.213)
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [http-nio-8888-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [http-nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [http-nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 22 ms
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [http-nio-8888-exec-4] e.u.i.c.crawler.CrawlController - Deleted contents of: /tmp/frontier ( as you have configured resumable crawling to false )
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [http-nio-8888-exec-4] e.u.i.c.crawler.CrawlController - Crawler 1 started
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:48:44 [http-nio-8888-exec-4] e.u.i.c.crawler.CrawlController - Crawler 2 started
[INFO ] 2019-04-17 16:4
```

Obviously I runing my service after the server started a lot of time, but the runtime log info is the same as the timestamp when the service started.

i'm new to logback,I don't know how this problem arises.I would be very grateful if you can provide some suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure you have to use `<timestamp` tag? IMHO what's happening is that it is evaluted at start time and it is expanding to `%d{2019-04-17 16:48:44}`. Try to replace it with `<property` and `value=`. edit: [the docs seem to say that I'm right](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#uniquelyNamed) the `timestamp` tag is evaluated at startup.

Comment: sorry,I am evaluating if my timestamp tag is correct, so I changed it to yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss. The latter result is also true. The above two files may be a bit inconsistent, sorry

Comment: many thx,you r right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<timestamp` tag is not meant to be used to contain properties. It is evaluted at start time and its value replaced by the result. This means that you end up with the equivalent of:

```
<pattern>[%-5level] %d{2019-04-17 16:48:44} [%thread] %logger{36} - %m%n
```

And thus the fixed datetime. [The documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) clarifies this:

> The `timestamp` element takes two mandatory attributes `key` and
>   `datePattern` and an optional `timeReference` attribute. The `key` attribute
>   is the name of the key under which the timestamp will be available to
>   subsequent configuration elements as a variable. The `datePattern`
>   attribute denotes the date pattern used to convert the current time
>   (at which the configuration file is parsed) into a string. The date
>   pattern should follow the conventions defined in SimpleDateFormat. The
>   `timeReference` attribute denotes the time reference for the time stamp.
>   **The default is the interpretation/parsing time of the configuration
>   file,** i.e. the current time. However, under certain circumstances it
>   might be useful to use the context birth time as time reference. This
>   can be accomplished by setting the `timeReference` attribute to
>   `"contextBirth"`.

Use a normal property instead:

```
<property name="MAXHISTORY" value="100" />
<property name="DATETIME" value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" />
<!-- Console printing -->
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder charset="utf-8">
        <pattern>[%-5level] %d{${DATETIME}} [%thread] %logger{36} - %m%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```